# How can I prevent automatic DPI scaling when HDTV on HDMI port is enabled?

Tags: display, windows-8.1-preview

When I have the TV on my HDMI port enabled, the DPI settings in Windows are scaled-up across all displays for what I guess would be the "10-foot experience" or the "10-foot UI" that I've heard Microsoft use in relation to TV displays.

It messes with everything from the lock screen to the Start screen and other native Windows views, to IE.

I don't know how to revert the change without disabling the TV.

In the Display control panel I have the sizing set at 100% and checked the box saying **Let me choose one scaling level for all my displays**.

The monitors and TV are all native 1080p displays.

Here's an example of how awful it is (Top: TV enabled):
[image: Scaling with TV enabled]
[image: Scaling with TV disabled]

Comment: So uncheck the box and use a different scaling for each monitor?

Comment: @psusi It was originally unchecked, but even so I don't see a way to set it per monitor (http://i.stack.imgur.com/dUWn3.png).

Comment: try it with the RTM again. this looks like a bug in the preview.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I guess it does look bad enough to be a bug. I'll get rid of the Windows 8 tag.

Comment: I mean the 8.1 RTM. test it there.